# Moodle WebServices How to get all Calendar events for an input userid

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile, moodle-theme

I want to show dead lines, messages and forum posts for a given user id on an external system.

looking for web services api in moodle to achieve this.

tried a few functions like core_calendar_get_calendar_upcoming_view but this does not give action events with deadlines.
core_calendar_get_action_events_by_course cant work out what other parameters are needed have included courseid as input parameter getting error Error in response - Missing following required key in a single structure: events